# How to correctly require Electron BrowserWindow in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm quite new to electron, nodejs and javascript but I've been picking up things steadily to nice results, but I've run into a little snag here, and have had no luck with searching for a similar issue. I however did find an example of someone using require in the same way, making me believe that this should work just fine.

In the electron quickstart, require('electron') is used for loading the BrowserWindow class. So now I'm trying to do the same thing but in my class. I attempt to load the module into a variable of the class, then use it later in CreateWindow. This results in a "this.BrowserWindow is not a constructor" exception. If I send the module from my Main.js, which loads the module the exact same way as in the electron quickstart, over to my WindowManager directly as a parameter, it does work. I could do that if there is no nicer way to do it, which I feel there is/should be.

Lastly, I am fairly confident the module does get loaded in some way, shape or form, because trying to require an invalid module gives me a "Cannot find module" exception.

So my question here is, why do I get an exception when I'd expect the same behavior as in the Electron Quickstart, and how to fix it correctly/elegantly.

My Class:

```
class WindowManager {

    constructor(CCC) {
        this.BrowserWindow = require('electron');
        this.ListManager = new (require('./ListManager.js').ListManager)(CCC);
        this.ListManager.RequestList("Root");
    }

    createWindow(BrowserWindow) {
        // Create the browser window.
        this.mainWindow = new this.BrowserWindow({
            height: 600,
            width: 800,
            webPreferences: {
                preload: 'preload.js',
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
        });

        // and load the index.html of the app.
        this.mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

        // Open the DevTools.
        // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

        // Emitted when the window is closed.
        this.mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
            // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
            // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
            // when you should delete the corresponding element.
            this.mainWindow = null
        })
    }
}
```

[Electron Quick Start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start):

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
// Create the browser window.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
})

// and load the index.html of the app.
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

// Open the DevTools.
// mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

// Emitted when the window is closed.
mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Electron Quick Start" sample code uses ECMAScript 6 **object destructuring** syntax (for the sake of brevity and convenience).

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

is equivalent to:

```
const app = require('electron').app;
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
```

So, in the constructor of the class `WindowManager`, the line:

```
this.BrowserWindow = require('electron');
```

should be instead:

```
this.BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that even more answers than I asked for and it's very much appreciated!